# GPGPU processing vs Graphic GPU

Tags: c++, gpu, game-engine

So I am developing a graphic API, I have already figured out how to create a window and draw pixels, all I'm missing right now is the GPU part. Can I use Sycl or OpenCL to replace it? So I want to use Sycl or OpenCL to access gpu and do the calculation part for my graphic. Is it an efficient way to use GPU?

Comment: Choices made always trade off one thing against another.  Only you know what things you're willing to trade.  Read the specifications of these systems, but more importantly decide exactly what your main goals are for your own system.  If you still don't have a clear idea, then write small tests to evaluate specific parts of the systems you wish to compare.  It's all about making an informed decision.  Only you know what you want.

Comment: i do not know if it is only me but I can not understand what you are asking. What is it that you are trying to do?

Comment: We do not know which calculations your graphic API intends to do, neither what hardware it should be able to run on, or who will be using it (only you or others).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use OpenCL to do graphics rendering. It is lightning fast when done right - for special applications faster than anything else - but you will have to implement everything from scratch: camera transformation from 3D to 2D screen coordinates, Bresenham algorithm for line/triangle rasterization, and z-buffer.

Think of it that way: An image is just an integer array. You can use OpenCL to write color values into the array at corresponding pixel coordinates. Then pass it to your graphics API as the framebuffer and draw it on the screen.

The critical parts on the GPU are parallelization and memory access:

1. Parallelization:

   - For raster graphics, you can parallelize over an array of lines / an array of triangles. Each GPU thread rasterizes a single line/triangle on the frame.
   - For raytracing graphics, you parallelize over the pixels on the frame. Each GPU thread computes the color for a single pixel.
2. Memory access: The arrays of lines/triangles must be in GPU memory at all time. PCIe data transfer of large arrays from/to the CPU in between frames will make it extremely slow.

The strategy for interactive graphics with OpenCL is as folows:

1. Initialize an array of lines / array of triangles in GPU memory. With a separate physics thread on the CPU, you can enqueue OpenCL kernels that compute some physics and update the line/triangle coordinates, all in GPU memory
2. Get camera parameters (rotation matrix from mouse movement, camera position, field of view etc.) on the CPU, and copy them to GPU memory
3. call the rasterization kernels on the GPU that rasterize all lines/triangles in parallel on the frame/z-buffer.
4. Copy the finished frame to CPU memory and hand it over to the graphics API.

Disclaimer: I have written my own raster/raytracing graphics engine in OpenCL from scratch. See [here](https://youtu.be/NQPgumd3Ei8) for a real time demo.